# Let us see our answers which has been deleted due to question deletion

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, deleted-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted)

This is quite depressing when you're writing an answer, you just refresh page after a while and you see that "Question was deleted by owner voluntary"

Would it be a good idea to just let people see their deleted answers which were deleted due to OP's decision? So I could use it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can view those questions at 10k reputation, not before.  Opening up deleted questions is a can of worms, one we've intentionally only exposed to the most experienced users.